# Google Plus API - Retrieve code programmatically

Tags: api, google-plus

I'm using Java with Google Plus API. I'm using OAuth 2.0. When a user is authenticated, an access `code` is returned in a browser. Now, given that the code must accompany a call to the `Google Plus API`, I currently have to manually copy the code and use it in making calls to the `Google Plus API`. What I wish to do, however, is to programmatically retrieve this code; eliminate the manual copying.

Any assistance will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're writing a command line or some other non-web application that uses the Google+ API. This throws a little bit of a wrench into the token delivery via HTTP redirect. Without the redirect there's no way for the OAuth web pages to communicate with your code and hence you must copy and paste it.

There is one work around that seems to work pretty well. You can set up a local web server, such as an embedded Jetty, and complete the OAuth flow by redirecting the user back to their locally running web server.

You can see an example of this implemented in oacurl which is hosted here: http://code.google.com/p/oacurl/

Comment: Thanks, Jenny. I'll try it out and then post my findings.

Comment: You are right , Jenny. Thanks a lot. This was extremely helpful.